# VOIP: pc-to-pc call and conference

Tags: c#, java, c++, voip

I want to create a software which will be able to make pc-to-pc calls (no telephone) with conference option. All the participants will use the software only. I am good at programming in different languages, platforms, and databases. But I didn't make this type of software before.

I will be developing two versions of the software. One for desktop another for web. So refer me a platform/language that will work in both the cases (at least with slight modification). :)

Can you refer me to some protocols and techniques for doing that? Also refer me to some compression techniques as the software will run on low bandwidth, too (64kbps).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will your application do better than Skype?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the VOIP world! Although I wish you a lot of success I'd like to warn you that you are trying to solve not so simple problem. There are many application you are describing. The first one was developed about 15 years ago. Since that time people were working hard to improve the voice quality and made some success. But they invested millions of $ and thousands of human years. You can write application from scratch and it will work as applications that were 15 years ago.

I'd recommend you to read about Voip and if you still want to create application exactly like Skype try to find existing voip engine and write just an application that wraps it.

Answer (score 0):

[Silverlight](http://silverlight.net) is pretty similar on desktop and web. See [Silverlight VoIP](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=silverlight+voip).